# OCCI getString with more than 16 bytes - access violation

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, occi

I am using OCCI to connect to an Oracle DB.
When I call:

```
std::string s = resultSet->getString(i);
```

and I receive 16 bytes or more , there is an access violation.

I could not find an answer for this in any website.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What platform, Oracle version and compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm running on Win 7, with VC10 and oracle client 11 (which I take the oraocci11.dll from).